# Conda - Get list of package starting with certain letter(s)

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

How can I get the list of package starting with certain character(s) in conda?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Conda List Command

The `conda list` command is sufficiently expressive to do this. Specifically, examining the usage signature for the command shows that it accepts a regex argument:

```bash
$ conda list -h
usage: conda list [-h] [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH] [--json] [-v] [-q]
                  [--show-channel-urls] [-c] [-f] [--explicit] [--md5] [-e]
                  [-r] [--no-pip]
                  [regex]

List linked packages in a conda environment.

Options:

positional arguments:
  regex                 List only packages matching this regular expression.
...
```

### Examples

Here are some examples using a regular expression to find packages starting with specific strings.

**Packages starting with "sci"**

```bash
$ conda list '^sci'
# packages in environment at /Users/merv/miniconda3/envs/anaconda_2020_11:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
scikit-image              0.17.2           py38h81aa140_0  
scikit-learn              0.23.2           py38h959d312_0  
scipy                     1.5.2            py38h2515648_0
```

**Packages starting with "num" or "sci"**

```bash
$ conda list '^(sci|num)'
# packages in environment at /Users/merv/miniconda3/envs/anaconda_2020_11:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numba                     0.51.2           py38h6440ff4_1  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py38hce01a72_0  
numpy                     1.19.2           py38h456fd55_0  
numpy-base                1.19.2           py38hcfb5961_0  
numpydoc                  1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
scikit-image              0.17.2           py38h81aa140_0  
scikit-learn              0.23.2           py38h959d312_0  
scipy                     1.5.2            py38h2515648_0
```

This should be preferred over using `grep` because it will preserve the header that `conda list` outputs.

Comment: This only worked for me with double quotes around the regex.  Specifically, `conda list '^ten'` returned no packages, but `conda list "^ten"` returned all packages starting with `ten`.  Maybe that's because I'm on Windows?